# SQL - Top 3 books sold each month (do NOT use window function)

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have one table call **sales** with following 5 columns

```
sales - order_id, book_id, date, price, qty (i.e. # of books per book_id)
```

I want to find the top 3 books (book_id) sold in revenue for each month. I want to avoid using the dense_rank() function.

Comment: There is no other reasonable alternative (I mean if you exclude window functions in general) in Redshift.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is an interview question I saw online, where the interviewer asked for a solution that should avoid using the window function

Comment: @user12562215 . . . Alternative solutions make sense in many databases, but not in Redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window functins are definitely the way to go here. This should be as simple as:

```
select *
from (
    select
        date_trunc('month', date) date_month,
        book_id,
        sum(qty) total_qty,
        rank() over(partition by date_trunc('month', date) order by sum(qty) desc) rn
    from sales
    group by date_trunc('month', date), book_id
) t
where rn <= 3
order by date_month, rn
```

Without window functions, one option would be to use a `having` clause with a correlated, aggregate subquery:

```
select
    date_trunc('month', date) date_month,
    book_id,
    sum(qty) total_qty
from sales s
group by date_trunc('month', date), book_id
having sum(qty) >= (
    select sum(qty)
    from sales s1
    where date_trunc('month', s1.date) = date_trunc('month', s.date)
    group by book_id
    order by sum(qty) desc
    limit 1 offset 2
)
order by date_month, total_qty desc
```